# How to install a jar file from target to a specific location using maven?

Tags: maven-2

Currently I have a simple maven project that is building a jar file and putting it inside `target/some-1.0.jar` when i run `mvn install`.

I want to copy this file to another location when I run `mvn deploy`.

Currently the location is on the same machine, but it would also be great if the solution could be applied for multiple targets, some of them being on other machines (scp deployment).

What is the easiest solution to do this? I would be nice, if you could include an example too.

Details: I have few jira plugins that are compiled as jar files and I just want to be able to run a single maven command that would copy the files to the server and eventually restart the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mvn deploy` is intended for deployment to a remote Maven repository. `mvn install` is used for copying to the local Maven repo (so actually, the jar is also ending up in `$HOME/.m2/repository`, as well as `target`).

I'm not sure what you're intending to do, but I suggest you look at deploying something like http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/ if you want Maven artifacts to be available to multiple machines. This will integrate nicely with the rest of Maven.

Edit: based on your updated question, it's probably best to investigate the Wagon ssh plugin, or see if there's an Ant plugin. A suitable phase would be pre-integration-test: install and deploy should be run **after** you've run your integration tests to check the artefact works as expected. Use profiles to distinguish the local vs. remote cases.